# What exactly is the "Data Sharing service" in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016

Windows Server 2016 (and Windows 10) contain the mysterious "Data Sharing service", which

- [happens to crash every now and then, polluting our service logs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc0ef38b-5576-404d-8aad-0287ae9659aa/event-error-the-data-sharing-service-service-terminated-with-the-following-error?forum=WinPreview2014General).
- Apparently, [even Microsoft employees don't know what it is](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cee780c-c55d-4a3a-bfe2-223a78206b1a/data-sharing-service?forum=win10itprosecurity) and just quote the service description *"Provides data brokering between applications"*-

What is it? What will break when it is disabled? Can event log messages about it crashing be safely ignored?

Comment: I'm not going to be able to answer, but Server 2016 has several suspect services that have to run.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0c8a3fde-1f9e-4474-b934-dd3428be7ce0/what-does-onesyncsvc-do

Answer (score 5):

Without directly answering the "what is it" question (since I don't personally know), there was a blog post about fixing the crashes at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcorejp/2016/12/22/collision-between-user-access-logging-service-and-data-sharing-service/ with translation notes at http://www.neighborgeek.net/2017/05/server-2016-data-sharing-service.html that basically comes down to running this service and another service in isolated service processes:

```
sc config ualsvc type=own
sc config dssvc type=own
```

Comment: Brilliant, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this blog a bit too late...  Nevertheless, if you still rely upon any MS Server Media Block (SMB) services (not so mysterious), this service NEEDS to be RUNNING for your device to be advertised on your internal network.